# How to get string from ASCII code in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, character, ascii

How can I get a character from a ASCII code in Apple's new Swift?

For example `65` would returns `"A"`.

Comment: If you know the code at compile time you just can use: `println("The Character A: \u{41}")` to print arbitrary unicode scalars. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_432 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

As a character:

```
let c = Character(UnicodeScalar(65))
```

Or as a string:

```
let s = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(65)))
```

Or another way as a string:

```
let s = "\u{41}"
```

(Note that the `\u` escape sequence is in hexadecimal, not decimal)

Comment: @M.J.K: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-point-of-a-character.

Comment: @nikoss: Updated so that it works with Swift 2 and 3. Thanks for letting me know!