# Swift: Check if first character of String is ASCII or a letter with an accent

Tags: swift, ascii, diacritics, nscharacterset

In Swift, how do I check whether the first character of a `String` is ASCII or a letter with an accent? *Wider* characters, like emoticons & logograms, don't count.

I'm trying to copy how the iPhone Messages app shows a person's initials beside their message in a group chat. But, it doesn't include an initial if it's an emoticon or a Chinese character for example.

I see `decomposableCharacterSet` & `nonBaseCharacterSet`, but I'm not sure if those are what I want.

Comment: [How can I get the Unicode code point of a Character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-point-of-a-character) and [http://www.asciitable.com/](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: What happens when a user has a chinese or arabic name?

Comment: @JoJoe it shows a [blank profile picture](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37096/iphone-messages-blank-person-icon).

Answer (score 3):

There are many Unicode Character with an accent.
Is this for you a character with an accent?

Ê
Ð
Ï
Ḝ
Ṹ
 é⃝

---

In Unicode there are combined characters, which are two unicode characters as one:

```
let eAcute: Character = "\u{E9}"                         // é
let combinedEAcute: Character = "\u{65}\u{301}"          // e followed by ́
// eAcute is é, combinedEAcute is é
```

For Swift the `Character` is the same!

Good reference is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

---

If you want to know the CodeUnit of the Characters in the String, you can use the `utf8` or `utf16` property. They are different!

```
let characterString: String = "abc"
for character in characterString.utf8 {
    print("\(character) ")
}
// output are decimal numbers: 97 98 99 
// output of only é: 195 169, used the combined é
```

Then you could check for ASCII alphabet A-Z as 65-90 and a-z as 97-122.
And then check for the standard accent grave and acute
À 192
Á 193
È 200
É 201
à 224
á 225
è 232
é 233
... and the combined ones and everything you like.

But there are symbols that look like a latin letter with accent, but doesn't have the same meaning!

You should make sure, that only these characters are accepted, that you want with the correct linguistic meaning.