# how to get a Character's Unicode in Swift programming language?

Tags: unicode, swift

For example, we have:

```
var char:Character="\u{1F496}"   //get a Character like a heart
```

How to do the opposite work, like how to get Character ("A")'s unicode.

Comment: Do you think this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-points-of-a-character

Comment: Try casting it to an integer, I don't know how that works in Swift but [here is an article about casting in swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html). This should give you the data in UTF-16, which should be useful to you.

Comment: @PicrofoSoftware Yes, what else should I do? Delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Can do something like that:

```
let char: Character = "\u{1F496}"
let value: Int = Int(NSString(string: String(chat)).characterAtIndex(0))
```

Comment: 'let dogString = ""
for codeUnit in dogString.utf16
{
    print("\(codeUnit) ")
}'   //it gives 55357 and 56374, while your code gives 55357, how to do the opposite work? From (55357, 56374) to  ""

Comment: @Allen Use these formulas to convert between Unicode code points and UTF-16 surrogate halves: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae

Comment: Thank you. And this helps (http://segmentfault.com/q/1010000000638151)

Answer (score 0):

`Character` does not represent a single Unicode code point, but rather a "Unicode grapheme cluster". To represent a single Unicode code point, you want `UnicodeScalar`.

```
let char: UnicodeScalar = "\u{1F496}"
println(char.value) // prints "128150"
```