# Is there a clean way to specify character literals in Swift?

Tags: swift, character, literals

Swift seems to be trying to deprecate the notion of a string being composed of an array of atomic characters, which makes sense for many uses, but there's an awful lot of programming that involves picking through datastructures that are ASCII for all practical purposes: particularly with file I/O. The absence of a built in language feature to specify a character literal seems like a gaping hole, i.e. there is no analog of the C/Java/etc-esque:

```
String foo="a"
char bar='a'
```

This is rather inconvenient, because even if you convert your strings into arrays of characters, you can't do things like:

```
let ch:unichar = arrayOfCharacters[n]
if ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' {...whatever...}
```

One rather hacky workaround is to do something like this:

```
let LOWCASE_A = ("a" as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
let LOWCASE_Z = ("z" as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
if ch >= LOWCASE_A && ch <= LOWCASE_Z {...whatever...}
```

This works, but obviously it's pretty ugly. Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: If you really want to treat a file as ASCII, then you can work with the Data class instead of the String class.

Answer (score 15):

`Character`s can be created from `String`s as long as those `String`s are only made up of a single character. And, since `Character` implements `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible`, Swift will do this for you automatically on assignment. So, to create a `Character` in Swift, you can simply do something like:

```
let ch: Character = "a"
```

Then, you can use the `contains` method of an `IntervalType` (generated with the [`Range` operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_126)) to check if a character is within the range you're looking for:

```
if ("a"..."z").contains(ch) {
    /* ... whatever ... */
}
```

Example:

```
let ch: Character = "m"
if ("a"..."z").contains(ch) {
    println("yep")
} else {
    println("nope")
}
```

Outputs:

> yep

---

**Update:** As @MartinR pointed out, the ordering of Swift characters is based on [Unicode Normalization Form D](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) which is **not** in the same order as ASCII character codes. In your specific case, there are more characters between `a` and `z` than in straight ASCII (`ä` for example). See @MartinR's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale/25775112#25775112) for more info.

If you need to check if a character is in between two ASCII character codes, then you may need to do something like your original workaround. However, you'll also have to convert `ch` to an `unichar` and not a `Character` for it to work (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-points-of-a-character) for more info on `Character` vs `unichar`):

```
let a_code = ("a" as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
let z_code = ("z" as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
let ch_code = (String(ch) as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)

if (a_code...z_code).contains(ch_code) {
    println("yep")
} else {
    println("nope")
}
```

Or, the even more verbose way without using `NSString`:

```
let startCharScalars = "a".unicodeScalars
let startCode = startCharScalars[startCharScalars.startIndex]

let endCharScalars = "z".unicodeScalars
let endCode = endCharScalars[endCharScalars.startIndex]

let chScalars = String(ch).unicodeScalars
let chCode = chScalars[chScalars.startIndex]

if (startCode...endCode).contains(chCode) {
    println("yep")
} else {
    println("nope")
}
```

***Note:** Both of those examples only work if the character only contains a single code point, but, as long as we're limited to ASCII, that shouldn't be a problem.*

Comment: Just note that the ordering of Swift strings or characters is not based on the ASCII code (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/25775112/1187415) . Eg `"a"..."z"` contains the character "ä". This may be desired or not.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I hadn't realized that. I updated the answer with that info.

Comment: That's a nice trick, which I'll keep in the bank for other kinds of logic. Still a bit high level though: when it comes to char-by-char file format parsing, where performance matters as much as precision, there's no substitute for being able to go back and forth between an int-like and string-like representation of a character. So char-literal is still needed.

Answer (score 11):

If you need C-style ASCII literals, you can just do this:

```
let chr = UInt8(ascii:"A") // == UInt8( 0x41 )
```

Or if you need 32-bit Unicode literals you can do this:

```
let unichr1 = UnicodeScalar("A").value // == UInt32( 0x41 )
let unichr2 = UnicodeScalar("é").value // == UInt32( 0xe9 )
let unichr3 = UnicodeScalar("").value // == UInt32( 0x1f600 )
```

Or 16-bit:

```
let unichr1 = UInt16(UnicodeScalar("A").value) // == UInt16( 0x41 )
let unichr2 = UInt16(UnicodeScalar("é").value) // == UInt16( 0xe9 )
```

All of these initializers will be evaluated at compile time, so it really is using an immediate literal at the assembly instruction level.

Answer (score 4):

The feature you want was [proposed to be in Swift 5.1](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0243-codepoint-and-character-literals.md), but that proposal was rejected for a few reasons:

1. #### Ambiguity

   The proposal as written, in the current Swift ecosystem, would have allowed for expressions like `'x' + 'y' == "xy"`, which was not intended (the proper syntax would be `"x" + "y" == "xy"`).
2. #### Amalgamation

   The proposal was two in one.

   First, it proposed a way to introduce single-quote literals into the language.

   Second, it proposed that these would be convertible to numerical types to deal with ASCII values and Unicode codepoints.

   These are both good proposals, and it was recommended that this be split into two and re-proposed. **Those follow-up proposals have not yet been formalized.**
3. #### Disagreement

   It never reached consensus whether the default type of `'x'` would be a [`Character`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character) or a [`Unicode.Scalar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar). The proposal went with `Character`, citing the [Principle of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), despite this lack of consensus.

You can read [the full rejection rationale here](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0243-codepoint-and-character-literals/21188/341).

---

The syntax might/would look like this:

```swift
let myChar = 'f' // Type is Character, value is solely the unicode U+0066 LATIN SMALL LETTER F
let myInt8: Int8 = 'f' // Type is Int8, value is 102 (0x66)
let myUInt8Array: [UInt8] = [ 'a', 'b', '1', '2' ] // Type is [UInt8], value is [ 97, 98, 49, 50 ] ([ 0x61, 0x62, 0x31, 0x32 ])

switch someUInt8 {
    case 'a' ... 'f': return "Lowercase hex letter"
    case 'A' ... 'F': return "Uppercase hex letter"
    case '0' ... '9': return "Hex digit"
    default: return "Non-hex character"
}
```

Comment: Mixed feelings about this... looks like it will do the job, but waiting 5 major versions for something that was available in Fortran in the 1950s is rather depressing.

Comment: @AlexClark I, for one, am glad that they're taking such major, irreversible changes so seriously, rather than just making a quick decision at the start that turns out to be the wrong decision (see also: JavaScript). And the fact that "5 major versions" translates to "about 5 years" is so delightful compared to the pace of other languages, where you might not see a major version in a decade, if ever.

Answer (score 3):

It also looks like you can use the following syntax:

```
Character("a")
```

This will create a `Character` from the specified single character string.

I have only tested this in Swift 4 and Xcode 10.1

Answer (score 1):

Why do I exhume 7 year old posts? Fun I guess? Seriously though, I think I can add to the discussion.

It is not a gaping hole, or rather, it is a deliberate gaping hole that explicitly discourages conflating a string of text with a sequence of ASCII bytes.

You absolutely can pick apart a String. A String implements `BidirectionalCollection` and has many ways to manipulate the atoms. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string.
But you have to get used to the more generalized notion of a String. It can be picked apart from the *User* perspective, which is a sequence of grapheme clusters, each (usually) which a visually separable appearance, or from the *encoding* perspective, which can be one of several (UTF32, UTF16, UTF8).

At the risk of overanalyzing the wording of your question:

- A data structure is conceptual, and independent of encoding in storage
- A data structure encoded as an ASCII string is just one kind of ASCII string
- By design the encoding of ASCII values 0-127 will have an identical encoding in  UTF-8, so loading that stream with a UTF8 API is fine
- A data structure encoded as a string where fields of the structure have UTF-8 Unicode string values is not an ASCII string, but a UTF-8 string itself
- A string is either ASCII-encoded or not; "for practical purposes" isn't a meaningful qualifier. A UTF-8 database field where 99.99% of the text falls in the ASCII range (where encodings will match), but occasionally doesn't, will present some nasty bug opportunities.

Instead of a terse and low-level equivalence of fixed-width integers and English-only text, Swift has a richer API that forces more explicit naming of the involved categories and entities. If you want to deal with ASCII, there's a name (method) for that, and if you want to deal with human sub-categories, there's a name for that, too, and they're totally independent of one another. There is a strong move away from ASCII and the English-centric string handling model of C. This is factual, not evangelizing, and it can present an irksome learning curve.

(This is aimed at new-comers, acknowledging the OP probably has years of experience with this now.)

For what you're trying to do there, consider:

```
let foo = "abcDeé@¶œŎO!@#"

foo.forEach { c in
    print((c.isASCII ? "\(c) is ascii with value \(c.asciiValue ?? 0); " : "\(c) is not ascii; ")
        + ((c.isLetter ? "\(c) is a letter" : "\(c) is not a letter")))
}
```

```
b is ascii with value 98; b is a letter
c is ascii with value 99; c is a letter
D is ascii with value 68; D is a letter
e is ascii with value 101; e is a letter
é is not ascii; é is a letter
@ is ascii with value 64; @ is not a letter
¶ is not ascii; ¶ is not a letter
œ is not ascii; œ is a letter
Ŏ is not ascii; Ŏ is a letter
O is ascii with value 79; O is a letter
! is ascii with value 33; ! is not a letter
@ is ascii with value 64; @ is not a letter
# is ascii with value 35; # is not a letter
```