# How do I cycle through the entire alphabet with Swift while assigning values?

Tags: swift, string, character

I am trying to cycle through the entire alphabet using Swift. The only problem is that I would like to assign values to each letter.

For Example: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 and so on until I get to z which would = 26.

How do I go through each letter in the text field that the user typed while using the values previously assigned to the letters in the alphabet?

After this is done, how would I add up all the letters values to get a sum for the entire word. I am looking for the simplest possible way to accomplish this but works the way I would like it to.

Comment: i think this is something to get you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102584/421755

Answer (score 8):

edit/update: **Xcode 12.5 • Swift 5.4**

---

```
extension Character {
    static let alphabetValue = zip("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 1...26).reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
    var lowercased: Character { .init(lowercased()) }
    var letterValue: Int? { Self.alphabetValue[lowercased] }
}
```

---

```
extension String {
    var wordValue: Int { compactMap(\.letterValue).reduce(0, +) }
}
```

---

```
Character("A").letterValue    // 1
Character("b").letterValue    // 2
Character("c").letterValue    // 3
Character("d").letterValue    // 4
Character("e").letterValue    // 5
Character("Z").letterValue    // 26
"Abcde".wordValue    // 15
```

Comment: I was trying to work out how to do this with the index of the array. But the range location of the word is a better approach.

Comment: @Buster he is changing the letters to lowercase before checking so yes.

Comment: How would I display this sum in a UILabel.

Comment: You need to connect a editing changed sent action to an ibaction where you can loop trough the letters and sum its values.

Comment: When I created the IBAction the error "Declaration is only valid at file scope" on the extension String { line. Do you want me to post the code I have as of now to see if you see any problems with it that I don't see

Comment: Just add a new file to your project (File > New > File > iOS Source Swift File ) call it main.swift and add those extensions there. You can also put them at the bottom of your view controller.

Comment: I dont understand this at all. I need to be able to know what this means so i can fix it if I want to change anything. This is very confusing.

Comment: What part you don't understand ? You just need to open your project add a new file (iOS Swift sourced file. Change the import Foundation to import UIKit and place those extensions there.

Comment: What it does it creates an array of characters for any string in this case an alphabet and try to find the letter. If found it returns the letter position which you can use as the index to extract the letter value.

Comment: Btw it is all in a single line  I can't understand what part is so confusing

Comment: The only thing you may have difficult to understand is the currying I use to find out the wordValue but I think the naming I choose is self explanatory

Comment: If you post a github or your project folder zipped I can fix it for you

Comment: I dont understand the extensions part. What is the point of it? Why do I need it? Can't I just put in the file I already have

Comment: You don't I will post it as a regular function for you

Comment: I just don't understand what the difference is between an extension and a regular function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74755/discussion-between-buster-and-leonardo-savio-dabus).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a function something like this...

```
func valueOfLetter(inputLetter: String) -> Int {
    let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", ... , "y", "z"] // finish the array properly

    for (index, letter) in alphabet {
        if letter = inputLetter.lowercaseString {
            return index + 1
        }
    }

    return 0
}
```

Then you can iterate the word...

```
let word = "hello"
var score = 0

for character in word {
    score += valueOfLetter(character)
}
```

Comment: There is an error saying: 'String' is not convertible to '([String], [String])

Comment: Ah, sorry I used the wrong enumeration method for getting the index, value tuple. I can't look now but if you search google for swift array you'll find the right method.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the letters by iterating over them and building a dictionary with letters corresponding to their respective values:

```
let alphabet: [String] = [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
]

var alphaDictionary = [String: Int]()
var i: Int = 0

for a in alphabet {
    alphaDictionary[a] = ++i
}
```

Use Swift's built-in Array `reduce` function to sum up the letters returned from your `UITextViewDelegate`:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    let sum = Array(textView.text.unicodeScalars).reduce(0) { a, b in
        var sum = a

        if let d = alphaDictionary[String(b).lowercaseString] {
            sum += d
        }

        return sum
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
func alphabetSum(text: String) -> Int {
    let lowerCase = UnicodeScalar("a")..."z"
    return reduce(filter(text.lowercaseString.unicodeScalars, { lowerCase ~= $0}), 0) { acc, x in
        acc + Int((x.value - 96))
    }
}


alphabetSum("Az") // 27 case insensitive
alphabetSum("Hello World!") // 124 excludes non a...z characters
```

The sequence `text.lowercaseString.unicodeScalars` ( lower case text as unicode scalar ) is filtered `filter` keeping only the scalars that *pattern match* `~=` with the `lowerCase` range.
`reduce` sums all the filtered scalar values *shifted* by -96 (such that 'a' gives 1 etc.). `reduce` starts from an *accumulator* (`acc`) value of `0`.
In this solution the pattern match operator will just check for the scalar value to be between `lowerCase.start` (a) and `lowerCase.end` (z), thus there is no lookup or looping into an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I've just put together the following function in swiftstub.com and it seems to work as expected.

```
func getCount(word: String) -> Int {
    let alphabetArray = Array(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    var count = 0

    // enumerate through each character in the word (as lowercase)
    for (index, value) in enumerate(word.lowercaseString) {
        // get the index from the alphabetArray and add it to the count
        if let alphabetIndex = find(alphabetArray, value) {
            count += alphabetIndex
        }
    }

    return count
}

let word = "Hello World"
let expected = 8+5+12+12+15+23+15+18+12+4

println("'\(word)' should equal \(expected), it is \(getCount(word))")

// 'Hello World' should equal 124 :)
```

The function loops through each character in the string you pass into it, and uses the `find` function to check if the character (value) exists in the sequence (alphabetArray), and if it does it returns the index from the sequence. The index is then added to the count and when all characters have been checked the count is returned.