# Apply a number to each letter in text swift2

Tags: numbers, swift2, textfield

I want to compare two entries in a `UITextField` giving a number to each letter and then compare the results of the addition of the letters from both fields.

Example:

> a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4 e=5 f=6
>
> textfield1= cae
>   textfield2= fca
>
> Result is:
>
> textfield1=9  and
>   textfield2=10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cycle through the entire alphabet with Swift while assigning values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889172/how-do-i-cycle-through-the-entire-alphabet-with-swift-while-assigning-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the unicode scalar representation of each character (look up ASCII tables) and sum these shifted by `-96` (such that `a -> 1`, `b -> 2` and so on). In the following, upper case letters will generate the same number value as lower case ones.

```
let foo = "cae"

let pattern = UnicodeScalar("a")..."z"
let charsAsNumbers = foo.lowercaseString.unicodeScalars
    .filter { pattern ~= $0 }
let sumOfNumbers = charsAsNumbers
    .reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value - 96 }

print(sumOfNumbers) // 9
```

Or, to simplify usage, create a function or `String` extension

```
/* as a function */
func getNumberSum(foo: String) -> UInt32 {
    let pattern = UnicodeScalar("a")..."z"
    return foo.lowercaseString.unicodeScalars
        .filter { pattern ~= $0 }
        .reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value - 96 }
}

/* or an extension */
extension String {
    var numberSum: UInt32 {
        let pattern = UnicodeScalar("a")..."z"
        return self.lowercaseString.unicodeScalars
            .filter { pattern ~= $0 }
            .reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value - 96 }
    }
}
```

Example usage for your case:

```
/* example test case (using extension) */
let textField1 = UITextField()
let textField2 = UITextField()
textField1.text = "cAe"
textField2.text = "FCa"

/* example usage */
if let textFieldText1 = textField1.text,
    let textFieldText2 = textField2.text {

        print(textFieldText1.numberSum) // 9
        print(textFieldText2.numberSum) // 10

        print(textFieldText1.numberSum
            == textFieldText2.numberSum) // false
}
```

Comment: Tks, that resolve my problem, but if i need upper case to?

Comment: @FabioCarlosSilva http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889172/how-do-i-cycle-through-the-entire-alphabet-with-swift-while-assigning-values

Comment: @FabioCarlosSilva You can append the `.lowercaseString` property to the `String` representation of each character in `getNumberSum(...)` function above. I've now included this in my answer (`getNumberSum()` updated). For an alternative method using extensions, see the linked thread provided by Leo.