# Strange behavior with swift compiler

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I have the following function in swift:

```
func f() -> Int
{
    let a = String("a")
    let b = a.unicodeScalars
    println(b[b.startIndex].value)

   //return b[b.startIndex].value
   return 1
}
```

If I uncomment the first return statement and comment the second one, then I get the compiler error:

> Could not find the member 'value'

Why this happens even when I have access to this member in the println function call?

**EDIT**:

In order to make the question more clear, consider the following code:

```
struct point {
    var x: UInt32
    var y: UInt32

    init (x: UInt32, y: UInt32) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

func f () -> Int {
    var arr = [point(x: 0, y: 0)]
    return arr[0].x
}
```

In this case, the compiler error is:

> UInt32 is not convertible to Int

My question is: Why the compiler errors are different even when the problem is the same in both cases?

Comment: It might simply be a compiler bug. If you split it into `let u = b[b.startIndex] ; return u.value` then you get the "correct" error message "UInt32 is not convertible to Int".

Comment: Agree, compiler doesn't always supply the correct error messages but the reason is very clearly the diff. between UInt32 and Int

Answer (score 2):

`value` returns a `UInt32`. Cast it to an `Int`.

```
return Int(b[b.startIndex].value)
```

Alternatively, you could have the function return a `UInt32` as @GoodbyeStackOverflow mentions.

```
func f() -> UInt32
```

Comment: beat me to it, either cast to Int or have the function return a UInt32

Comment: My question is why the error is "Could not find the member 'value'"

Answer (score 0):

Return this instead:

```
return Int(b[b.startIndex].value)
```

The issue is that b[...].value returns a UInt32, which starting Swift 1.2 no longer converts to Int.

Comment: My question is why the error is "Could not find the member 'value'"

Comment: My bad for omitting that. Then I guess I'm not entirely sure. Up-voting for good question.