# Converting Swift String to UTF-8 and doing arithmetic using char's ASCII value

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, swift, utf-8

I am trying to convert a legacy Objective-C function to Swift and running into some roadblocks with it. Here is the Objective-C function -

```
- (SHCardType)cardType:(NSString *)cardNum {
    if (cardNum.length <= 0) {
        return SHCTUnknown;
    }
    const char *s = [cardNum UTF8String];

    if (sizeof(cardTypes[0]) == 0) {
        return SHCTUnknown;
    }
    int cardsCount = sizeof(cardTypes) / sizeof(cardTypes[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < cardsCount; i++) {
        int dig = log10(cardTypes[i].max) + 1;
        int n = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < dig; j++) {
            n = n * 10 + (s[j] - '0');
        }

        if ((cardTypes[i].min <= n) && (n <= cardTypes[i].max)) {
            SHCardType cardType = cardTypes[i].cardType;
            int numLength = 16;
            if (cardType == SHCTAmericanExpress) {
                // Length is 15. Should confirm its type before all card number is entered.
                return cardType;
            } else if (cardType == SHCTDinersClubCarteBlanche || cardType == SHCTDinersClubenRoute || cardType == SHCTDinersClubInternational || cardType == SHCTDinersClubUnitedStatesCanada) {
                numLength = 14;
            }

            // For DinersClubCarteBlanche card, the length may be 16.
            if (numLength == cardNum.length || cardType == SHCTDinersClubCarteBlanche || cardType == SHCTDinersClubInternational) {
                return cardType;
            }
        }
    }

    return SHCTUnknown;
}
```

A couple of lines I am having trouble finding the Swift equivalent's for is

```
const char *s = [cardNum UTF8String];
```

Is there a Swift function I can use to convert a String to UTF-8

```
n = n * 10 + (s[j] - '0');
```

How do I represent the character '0' in swift. Can I use the '-' operand with it?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the automatic conversion offered in Xcode 7?

Comment: @AidanGomez This tool only converts Swift 1 to Swift 2, it doesn't translate Objective-C...

Comment: well there are some web tools ( like http://iswift.org/try ), question also is, why to do it in first place as you can call Objective-C code from swift very easily ...

Comment: If you're going to port over, then check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html and make sure you're conforming to the guide's approach.

Comment: Please ask about one specific item per question; that way someone else who has the same issue can easily find your question and the answer they need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let s = cardNum.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! // s is an Array<Int8>
...
let CHAR_ZERO : Int8 = 48
n = n * 10 + (s[j] - CHAR_ZERO);
```

It's cumbersome to convert a character to its integer value in the ASCII table in Swift. So you may as well define it as an integer constant.

**Edit:** if you want a safer way to do the unwrapping:

```
let s : Array<Int8>
if cardNum.canBeConvertedToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    s = cardNum.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
} else {
    s = []
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: For `var val: Int8 = s[j]`, I get an error `cannot subscript a value to type '[CChar]?' with index of type 'int'`

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? You may have forgotten the `!` at the end

Comment: Using Swift 1.2 at the moment.

Comment: You may have forgotten the `!` at the end

Comment: That was indeed it! Is there a better way to write `let s = cardNum.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!` rather than force unwrapping to avoid a runtime exception?

Comment: Edited my answer for a safer unwrapping.

Answer (score 1):

From [How can I get the Unicode code point(s) of a Character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-points-of-a-character)

```
let ch: Character = "A"
let s = String(ch).unicodeScalars
s[s.startIndex].value // returns 65
```

So perhaps try:

```
let z = "0".unicodeScalars
s[j] - z[z.startIndex].value
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This dint work but @Zoff Dino 's answer worked for me

Comment: @tbag just tested and this is functioning.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure but, you can try this:

```
func cardType(cardNum: String) -> SHCardType {
    if cardNum.length <= 0 {
        return SHCTUnknown
    }
    let s: Character = cardNum.UTF8String()
    if sizeof([0]) == 0 {
        return SHCTUnknown
    }
    var cardsCount: Int = sizeof() / sizeof([0])
    for var i = 0; i < cardsCount; i++ {
        var dig: Int = log10(cardTypes[i].max) + 1
        var n: Int = 0
        for var j = 0; j < dig; j++ {
            n = n * 10 + (s[j] - "0")
        }
        if (cardTypes[i].min <= n) && (n <= cardTypes[i].max) {
            var cardType: SHCardType = cardTypes[i].cardType
            var numLength: Int = 16
            if cardType == SHCTAmericanExpress {
                return cardType
            }
            else {
                if cardType == SHCTDinersClubCarteBlanche || cardType == SHCTDinersClubenRoute || cardType == SHCTDinersClubInternational || cardType == SHCTDinersClubUnitedStatesCanada {
                    numLength = 14
                }
            }
            if numLength == cardNum.length || cardType == SHCTDinersClubCarteBlanche || cardType == SHCTDinersClubInternational {
                return cardType
            }
        }
    }
    return SHCTUnknown
}
```