# How to extract emojis from a string?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a way to take a `String` and extract Emoji characters.
I know that Emojis are part of Unicode so I need to remove a certain subset of Unicode characters. I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Read about Swift strings https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: What is your goal I don't understand your question...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The Set of Emoji characters

First of all we need a `Set` containing the unicode values representing the emoji.

> **Disclaimer**
>
> For this answer I am using the range of Emoticons (1F601-1F64F) and Dingbats (2702-27B0) to show you the solution. However keep in mind that you should add [further ranges](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) depending on your needs.

### Extending Character

Now we need a way to calculate the Unicode Scalar Code Point of a Character. For this I am using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-points-of-a-character).

```
extension Character {
    private var unicodeScalarCodePoint: Int {
        let characterString = String(self)
        let scalars = characterString.unicodeScalars
        return Int(scalars[scalars.startIndex].value)
    }
}
```

### Extending String

This extension does allow you to extract the emoji characters from a  `String`.

```
extension String {
    var emojis:[Character] {
        let emojiRanges = [0x1F601...0x1F64F, 0x2702...0x27B0]
        let emojiSet = Set(emojiRanges.flatten())
        return self.characters.filter { emojiSet.contains($0.unicodeScalarCodePoint) }
    }
}
```

### Testing

```
let sentence = " hello world "
sentence.emojis // ["", ""]
```