# Extract emoji (unicode) from NSString

Tags: objective-c, swift, unicode, emoji

I have to parse some strings and extract emojis.

I can't found any good solution to do it.

Let say that i have this string:

" xxx  sss  "

How can I get these 2 emojis?

Note that: " ==  +  (Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick Type-6)"

Comment: You can try some Regex

Comment: With regard to the Emoji modifiers, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104152/how-to-know-if-two-emojis-will-be-displayed-as-one-emoji.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106059/how-to-extract-emojis-from-a-string ?

Comment: finally i found this that work VERY well : https://github.com/GabrielMassana/SearchEmojiOnString-iOS

Answer (score 1):

This code works only in the latest iOS 10 SDK, and cannot detect some combined emojis, but if that's OK with you, please try:

```
func emojis(_ str: String) -> [String]  {
    //You may need to add some extra characters as "Umbrella on ground" does not have property "Emoji_Presentation".
    let emojiPattern1 = "[\\p{Emoji_Presentation}\\u26F1]" //Code Points with default emoji representation
    let emojiPattern2 = "\\p{Emoji}\\uFE0F" //Characters with emoji variation selector
    let emojiPattern3 = "\\p{Emoji_Modifier_Base}\\p{Emoji_Modifier}" //Characters with emoji modifier
    let emojiPattern4 = "[\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F1FF][\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F1FF]" //2-letter flags
    let pattern = "\(emojiPattern4)|\(emojiPattern3)|\(emojiPattern2)|\(emojiPattern1)"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
    let matches = regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count))
    return matches.map{(str as NSString).substring(with: $0.range)}
}

print(emojis(" xxx  sss  ")) //->["", ""]
```

---

(UPDATE)Removed some errors in above code. And a little try to detect some combined emojis.

```
func emojisIncludingCombined(_ str: String) -> [String]  {
    //You may need to add some extra characters as "Umbrella on ground" does not have property "Emoji_Presentation".
    let emojiPattern1 = "[\\p{Emoji_Presentation}\\u26F1]" //Code Points with default emoji representation
    let emojiPattern2 = "\\p{Emoji}\\uFE0F" //Characters with emoji variation selector
    let emojiPattern3 = "\\p{Emoji_Modifier_Base}\\p{Emoji_Modifier}" //Characters with emoji modifier
    let emojiPattern4 = "[\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F1FF][\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F1FF]" //2-letter flags
    let pattern = "\(emojiPattern4)|\(emojiPattern3)|\(emojiPattern2)|\(emojiPattern1)"
    let combinedPattern = "(?:\(pattern))(?:\\u200D(?:\(pattern)))*"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: combinedPattern, options: [])
    let matches = regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count))
    return matches.map{(str as NSString).substring(with: $0.range)}
}
print(emojisIncludingCombined("ab‍❤️‍‍c")) //->["", "‍❤️‍‍", ""]
```

---

**UPDATE2**

An example which works in Swift 2/iOS 9 SDK.

```
func emojis(str: String) -> [String]  {
    //You may need to add "refine" (or "tune") emojiPattern1...emojiPattern4.
    let emojiPattern1 = "[\\u2600-\\u27BF\\U0001F300-\\U0001F77F\\U0001F900-\\U0001F9FF]" //Code Points with default emoji representation
    let emojiPattern2 = "[\\u2600-\\u27BF\\U0001F300-\\U0001F77F\\U0001F900–\\U0001F9FF]\\uFE0F" //Characters with emoji variation selector
    let emojiPattern3 = "[\\u2600-\\u27BF\\U0001F300-\\U0001F77F\\U0001F900–\\U0001F9FF][\\U0001F3FB-\\U0001F3FF]" //Characters with emoji modifier
    let emojiPattern4 = "[\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F1FF][\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F1FF]" //2-letter flags
    let pattern = "\(emojiPattern4)|\(emojiPattern3)|\(emojiPattern2)|\(emojiPattern1)"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
    let matches = regex.matchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count))
    return matches.map{(str as NSString).substringWithRange($0.range)}
}

let str1 = "Hello, my name is Jason   how are you ?"
let str4 = "I am going to the ⛱beach with some monkeys "
let str5 = "Japan boy ♏️Scorpis" //="\u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F5}Japan \u{1F466}\u{1F3FB}boy \u{264f}\u{FE0F}Scorpis"
let str6 = " xxx  sss  "
let str7 = "ab‍❤️‍‍"

print(emojis(str1)) //->["", ""]
print(emojis(str4)) //->["⛱", "", ""]
print(emojis(str5)) //->["", "", "♏️"]
print(emojis(str6)) //->["", ""]
print(emojis(str7)) //->["", "", "❤️", "", ""]

func emojisIncludingCombined(str: String) -> [String]  {
    //You may need to add "refine" (or "tune") emojiPattern1...emojiPattern4.
    let emojiPattern1 = "[\\u2600-\\u27BF\\U0001F300-\\U0001F77F\\U0001F900-\\U0001F9FF]" //Code Points with default emoji representation
    let emojiPattern2 = "[\\u2600-\\u27BF\\U0001F300-\\U0001F77F\\U0001F900–\\U0001F9FF]\\uFE0F" //Characters with emoji variation selector
    let emojiPattern3 = "[\\u2600-\\u27BF\\U0001F300-\\U0001F77F\\U0001F900–\\U0001F9FF][\\U0001F3FB-\\U0001F3FF]" //Characters with emoji modifier
    let emojiPattern4 = "[\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F1FF][\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F1FF]" //2-letter flags
    let pattern = "\(emojiPattern4)|\(emojiPattern3)|\(emojiPattern2)|\(emojiPattern1)"
    let combinedPattern = "(?:\(pattern))(?:\\u200D(?:\(pattern)))*"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: combinedPattern, options: [])
    let matches = regex.matchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count))
    return matches.map{(str as NSString).substringWithRange($0.range)}
}

print(emojisIncludingCombined(str7)) //->["", "‍❤️‍‍"]
```

As commented in the code, `emojiPattern1`...`emojiPattern4` are not representing a complete set of emojis available in iOS. (Including the codes for Swift 3.) You may need to modify the patterns.

Comment: i need iOS 9 support.

Comment: @RedMak, updated, please try.