# Checking if a given character is an emoji in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring, emoji

I have an `NSString` and would like to check if a given character at a certain index is an emoji.

However, there doesn't seem to be any reliable way to create an `NSCharacterSet` of emoji characters, since they change from iOS update to update. And a lot of the available solutions rely on Swift features such as `UnicodeScalar`. All solutions seem to involve hardcoding the codepoint values for emojis.

As such, is it possible to check for emojis at all?

Comment: There's is no provided API that checks just for Emoji. I haven't tried it but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472163/1226963 which uses an interesting solution to detecting an Emoji. It seems to treat any non-all black character as an Emoji.

Comment: I think this helper function should help you: https://gist.github.com/cihancimen/4146056.

Comment: The function in the gist doesn't seem to cover all emojis, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a complicated question because Unicode is complicated, but you can use `NSRegularExpression` to do this:

```
    NSString *s = @"where's the emoji  ?";
    NSRegularExpression *r = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\p{Emoji_Presentation}" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSRange range = [r rangeOfFirstMatchInString:s options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];
    NSLog(@"location %lu length %lu", (unsigned long)range.location, (unsigned long)range.length);
```

produces:

```
2019-01-16 18:07:42.629 emoji[50405:6837084] location 18 length 2
```

I'm using the `\p{Unicode property name}` pattern to match characters which have the specified Unicode property. I'm using the property `Emoji_Presentation` to get those character which present as Emoji by default. You should review [Unicode® Technical Standard #51 — Annex A: Emoji Properties and Data Files](http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Properties_and_Data_Files) and the data files linked in A.1 to decide which property you actually care about.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122453/1226963 which seems to indicate that it's far more complex than just using `Emoji_Presentation`.