# How can I get unicode number of a character?

Tags: swift, unicode

How can I get the **Unicode number** of a given string ?

For example, Cyrillic Small Letter Er **U+0440** stands for "р"

## How can I get "U+0440" or "0440"?

====Technical information====

Unicode number: U+0440

HTML-code: &#1088

```
var myString = "р"
for scalar in myString.unicodeScalars {
    print("\(scalar.value) ") // print: 1008
}
```

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-points-of-a-character

Comment: `"Hello".unicodeScalars.map{$0.value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

440 in hex is equal to 1088 in decimal:

```
var myString = "р"
for scalar in myString.unicodeScalars {
    print(String(scalar.value, radix: 16))
}
```