# How to convert Unicode character to hexadeximal code points in swift?

Tags: swift, unicode

I have a character like this:

> "é"

And I need to convert it to a hexadeximal code points like this

> "\u{65}\u{301}"

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the Unicode code point(s) of a Character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-points-of-a-character)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39045270/2020490